# Java Remote Connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, server, relational-database

Assuming I have this Connection String on my local host:

```
public static Connection ConnectDB(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/supermarket", "root","");      
        return con;
    }
```

When I am trying to Connect to this system from another. What should I change to access the database?

Say my IP Address on the system is : 192.168.137.1

Comment: replace "localhost" with that ip address.

Comment: Start by replacing `localhost` to the IP Address. I think you'll have to provide the port number as well. Something like `x.x.x.x:yyyy`

Comment: your statement would become

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.137.1:6036/supermarket", "root","");

Use appropriate IP and Portnumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your statement would become

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<IP Address>:<Port>/supermarket", "root","");
```

Use appropriate IP and Portnumber

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.137.1:6036‌​/supermarket", "root","");
```

Answer (score 1):

To access a `mysql` db remotely, you have 3 things to consider:

1. Provide the right ip address and port of your remote server
2. Make sure that the firewall of your server is properly configured to allow remote accesses on your server port
3. Grant the required privileges to your user to allow remote accesses

Command to execute to grant privileges to your user to access to the db from any remote hosts:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON supermarket.*
TO 'root'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is ok. But localhost represents your local machine IP.

You should change following things:

Make **db.properties** File

```
connection=jdbc:mysql://192.168.137.1:6036‌​/supermarket
username=root
password=xyz
```

And Add following code in main method

```
public static Connection ConnectDB(){
    try{
       FileReader reader=new FileReader("db.properties");  

    Properties p=new Properties();  
    p.load(reader); 

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(p.getProperty("connection"),p.getProperty("username"),p.getProperty("password"));      
        return con;
    }
```